# Python 3 doesn't read unicode file on a new server

Tags: unicode, python-3.x

My webpages are served by a script that dynamically imports a bunch of files with

```
try:
    with open (filename, 'r') as f:
        exec(f.read())
except IOError: pass
```

(actually, can you suggest a better method of importing a file? I'm sure there is one.)

Sometimes the files have strings in different languages, like

```
# contents of language.ru
title = "Название"
```

Those were all saved as UTF-8 files. Python has no problem running the script in command line or serving a page from my MacBook:

```
    OK: [server command line] python3.0 page.py /index.ru
    OK: http://whitebox.local/index.ru
```

but it throws an error when trying to serve a page from a server we just moved to:

```
      157     try:
      158         with open (filename, 'r') as f:
      159             exec(f.read())
      160     except IOError: pass
      161 
      /usr/local/lib/python3.0/io.py in read(self=, n=-1)
      ...
      UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 627: ordinal not in range(128)
```

All the files were copied from my laptop where they were perfectly served by Apache. What is the reason?

**Update:** I found out the default encoding for `open()` is platform-dependent so it was `utf8` on my laptop and `ascii` on server. I wonder if there is a per-program function to set it in Python 3 (`sys.setdefaultencoding` is used in `site` module and then deleted from the namespace).

Comment: `import` usually works to import files. Any reason it doesn't work for you?

Comment: Have a look at [sys.getfilesystemencoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding). On Linux you should ensure that the locale variable `LC_CTYPE` has a sane value as it defines the meaning of filenames and is used by Python as well. `LC_CTYPE` comes from either the environment variable of the same name or is inferred by `LC_ALL`. Running the `locale` command will tell you the current values.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8')`.
See [Python 3 docs for open](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#open).

Answer (score 1):

Use codecs library, I'm using python 2.6.6 and I do not use the usual open with encoding argument:

```
import codecs
codecs.open('filename','r',encoding='UTF-8')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
with open(fname, 'r', encoding="ascii", errors="surrogateescape") as f:
    data = f.read()

# make changes to the string 'data'

with open(fname + '.new', 'w',
           encoding="ascii", errors="surrogateescape") as f:
    f.write(data)
```

more information is on [python unicode documents](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)